# Can you use Javascript Remoting in a public (unauthenticated) Force.com site

Tags: force.com-sites, javascript-remoting

I would like to use Javascript remoting, on a public unauthenticated site.

Does Force.com let you do this?

I am assuming yes, and it is the same as VisualForce doing the rendering.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use JavaScript Remoting to communicate with the controller on a Force.com Sites page that is unauthenticated. Like on a Visualforce page that uses the traditional controller view state and properties, the running user in this scenario is the guest user for your Site.